# jquery resetting and setting variables

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to create slidingUp divs with variable 'top' heights, so that one div may slideUp 700px, while another (with less content) slidesUp only 400px.  Currently, the divs all slideUp at the same height. There are no div height declarations in the css. My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
            var oldHeight;  
    $('a.menubtn').click(function(){              
            var newHeight;
            if ($(this.id) == 'work') {
                  newHeight = 700;  
                  }
                  else { if ($(this.id) == 'services') {
                      newHeight = 400;
                  }
                  else { if ($(this.id) == 'about') {
                      newHeight = 400;
                  }
                  else {
                      newHeight = 300;
                  }
                  }
                  }

            if ($('.active').length > 0) {

                $('.active').removeClass('active').animate({'top': '+=' + oldHeight + 'px'}, '200');
                $('div#contents_'+ this.id).addClass('active').animate({'top': '-=' + newHeight + 'px'}, '200');
                oldHeight = newHeight;
                }
                else 
    $('div#contents_'+ this.id).addClass('active').animate({'top': '-=' + newHeight + 'px'}, '200');
                oldHeight = newHeight;
                }
    return(false);
    });               
})
```

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements are wrong.

This:

```
$(this.id) == 'work'  // here you're comparing a jQuery object to 'work'
```

should be:

```
this.id == 'work'     // here you're comparing the actual ID value to 'work'
```

It would be cleaner if you changed the structure of the `if` statements to be like this:

```
if (this.id == 'work') {
    newHeight = 700;  
} else if (this.id == 'services') {
    newHeight = 400;
} else if (this.id == 'about') {
    newHeight = 400;
} else {
    newHeight = 300;
}
```